# Preserve order of keys after parsing JSON to a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to keep the 'column' order in a Pandas DataFrame after parsing JSON data using `json_normalize`.

Some of my code:

```
for row in json_data["results"]["companies"]:
    if df is None:
        df = json_normalize(row["companie"])
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, json_normalize(row["companie"])])
```

Now the columns are sorted alphabetically but I want to keep them in the same order as in the JSON data.

Comment: You lost the order when you parsed the JSON. Load the JSON data into an `OrderedDict`, see the duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For completeness and future use :   `json_data = requests.get(url).json(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)`